# Cmake не находит gRPC через find_package. Make Error at client_grpc/CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)

Tags: c++, cmake, google-protobuf, grpc

устанавливал gRPC по гайду на сайте [quick start gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/) написал в cmake:

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC REQUIRED)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
build task channel
CMake Error at client_grpc/CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindgRPC.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "gRPC", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gRPC" with any of
  the following names:

    gRPCConfig.cmake
    grpc-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gRPC" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "gRPC_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "gRPC"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Работаю в Clion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед `find_package` укажите директорию, куда установили `gRPC`. Например, у меня это `/usr/local/lib/grpc/`, где находятся поддиректории `bin, include, lib, share`.
Для этого добавьте

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/lib/grpc/")
```

Answer (score 0):

@magrif
Не получается, добавил тот путь только у себя.
Вот часть cmake файла

```
file(GLOB HEADER_LIST CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
        "${NESTING_CLIENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hpp")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/include/grpc/" "/usr/include/google/protobuf/")
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${PROTO_SRC_DIR})
include_directories(${PROTO_SRC_DIR})
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC REQUIRED)
```

[image: директория с grpc]